# How host Webserver from Outside Network

Tags: apache, nginx, raspberry-pi, webserver

I have subscribed to Local Broadband plan in Delhi, They have 1 static ip through which their all subscribe use it. When I Enter my ip from outside then it will forwarded to their Local IP management Software Page. How can i access to my web server, Is there my port forwarding technique like through unique port i can access to my localhost from out side or any other way. Even Dynamic DNS service like no-ip isnt working. they all are landing on same IP Management page.

Thank You in Advance.

Note: Using Nginx on Raspberry Pi.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is with your Local Broadband company. Sounds like they need to do the port forwarding, or you from that "management page" you get to access.

You have to be able to forward port 80 from your router (the one with the Public Static IP) to the private (NAT) IP of the PI; both on port 80.